# Inherit Symfony Validation configurations for objects that extend a common abstract class

Tags: php, validation, symfony, inheritance

I have two entities in a Symfony project that extend a common abstract class and I have defined a Symfony Validation configuration per entity using the XML configuration format.

Because the two entities have a common set of properties inherited from the abstract class, I have duplicate the rules for each into their respective validation configurations.

This is obviously not ideal as someone may change the rules for one and neglect to update the rules for the other.

**Is there a strategy with the XML configuration where I can define a validation configuration for the abstract class, and then have a configuration for each of the entities that inherit the abstract class validation?**

It seems like this is possible with with the Annotation configuration, or PHP configuration.  But I don't see how to do the same with XML or YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony will automatically examine the hierarchy of a class and load any validators defined for each class that is in involved.

So take the following PHP class:

```
<?php

abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected $inheritedProperty;
}

class MyConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    protected $myProperty;
}
```

The validator for `MyConcreteClass`, will only describe it's own properties, (i.e. `$myProperty`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
                        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">
    <class name="MyConcreteClass">
        <property name="myProperty">
            <constraint name="NotBlank" />
        </property>
    </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

The validator for `AbstractClass`, will only describe it's own properties, (i.e. `$inheritedProperty`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping
                        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">
    <class name="AbstractClass">
        <property name="inheritedProperty">
            <constraint name="NotBlank" />
        </property>
    </class>
</constraint-mapping>
```

When validating a `MyConcreteClass` object, Symfony will automatically identify that `MyConcreteClass` extends `AbstractClass` and that it needs to load the `AbstractClass` validator in addition to `MyConcreteClass` validator -- there is no additional configuration required.